# Interior of $A=\{x\in \Bbb{R^n} : \vert x \vert \leq 1\}$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification

What is the interior of $A=\{x\in \Bbb{R^n} : \vert x \vert \leq 1\}$? I claim it is the set of $\{y\in \Bbb{R^n}:\vert y\vert<1\}.$ This is because

$\exists h\in\Bbb{R}$ such that $\vert y \vert=1-h.$ Also, $\exists z\in \Bbb{R^n}$ s.t $\vert y-z\vert < h$. Therefore $\vert z-0\vert=\vert z \vert\leq\vert y-0\vert+\vert y-z\vert<1-h+h=1$. Therefore $z\in A$ and $y$ is an interior point of $A$. What's wrong with this proof? I don't believe it's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Proof 1**:

$\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}^n} \newcommand{\eps}{\epsilon} \newcommand{\ball}[1]{B_{\eps}(#1)}$
The interior of $A$ is the largest open set contained in $A$.

Let $B = \{x \in\R~|~|x| <1\}$.

Claim 1: $B$ is open.

Let $a \in B$ be arbitrary. Then, $|a| < 1$ and let $\eps = (1-|a|)/2$. For all $y \in \R$, $|y-a| < \eps$ implies $|y| < 1$, that is, $B$ is open. Note that $|y-a| \geq |y| - |a|$ from triangle inequality.

Claim 2: $B$ is the largest open set contained in $A$.

Suppose $B$ is not the largest open subset of $A$. Then, there is a non-empty subset $C$ of $A$ that is disjoint from $B$ and $B \cup C$ is an open subset of $A$. By the conditions, $C \subseteq \{x\in\R~|~|x| = 1\}$. The disjoint union of $B$ and $C$ is not open, which is a contradiction.

Therefore, $B$ is the interior of $A$.

**Proof 2**:

Here is another proof using a different definition you would like:

If $B$ satisfies
$$
\forall x \in \R: x \in B \Leftrightarrow \exists \eps >0 :\ball{x} \subseteq A
$$

$B$ is the interior of $A$.

We can easily show the $\Rightarrow$ direction as we did previously. We now only need to show the necessity, whose contrapositive is

$$
\forall x \in \R: x \not\in B \Rightarrow \forall \eps >0 : \exists y \in \ball{x} : y \not\in A
$$

Let $a \not\in B$. Then, $|a| \geq 1$. For each $\eps > 0$, let $y = a(1+\frac{\eps}{2|a|})$. Then, $|y| = |a|(1+\frac{\eps}{2|a|}) = |a| +\eps/2 > 1$, which means $y \not\in A$. Furthermore, $|y - a| = |\frac{\eps a}{2|a|}| = \eps/2 < \eps$, that is, $y \in \ball{x}$.

This proof looks more useful.

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is correct but it does not show that $B:= \{ y\in\mathbb{R}^n : |y| < 1\}$ is the interior of $A$.

To prove the claim, first of all recall that the interior of $A$ is the set of all interior points of $A$, i.e. of all the points that have a open neighborhood contained in $A$. If $|z|=1-h<1$ then the ball with center $z$ and radius $h/2$ is contained in $A$, hence $z$ is an interior point. If $|z|=1$ then every open ball around $z$ will contain a point with norm greater than $1$, hence $z$ does not have a open neighborhood contained in $A$ and therefore is not an interior point. This shows that the set of interior points is exactly $B$.